# Haskell, create "multi-type" list

Tags: haskell, types

Is there a way to make haskell type this expression?

```
ls  = [4, 3.2, True, "home"]
```

It's a challenge a friend gived to me, but no ideas come around, also didn't tell me if that is possible, so maybe I'm wasting precious time.

Comment: The types it contains are completely arbitrary?

Comment: Not exactly that expression, but you can use arbitrary types in a list with https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type, but working with these values after they are in the list is very limited, because types of these are checked at compile-time, rather than run time - this is generally considered an antipattern.

Comment: What use would such list be? What are you going to do with it afterwards? The answer to this question will determine how to do it.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin supose I want to print all the element of that list

Comment: @DamianLattenero, then Existential Types can help you with that... look at section 2.1 here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type - the only caveat is that all of these types must have a Show instance, which makes sense, since I'm assuming you want to use `print` which requires a `Show` instance.

Comment: @AdamWagner I tryed adding Show a => a ... etc, and didn't compile :/

Comment: @Carcigenicate mmm not completely, supose at least you want and can print all the element inside

Comment: @DamianLattenero, see my answer below, I think you probably missed the language extension... It's not spelled out clearly on that page I sent you to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As joke, you can do like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.String                                                          

instance Num Bool where                                                     
    fromInteger 0 = False
    fromInteger _ = True

instance Fractional Bool where
    fromRational 0 = False
    fromRational _ = True

instance IsString Bool where
    fromString "" = False
    fromString _  = True

ls = [4, 3.2, True, "home"]
```

But this doesn't have sense.

---

If the form of the expression is not fundamental, then as wrote in the comments, you can use the `ExistentialType`. But there are many variants to do that. From use `Data.Dynamic` to custom existential type.

For example, with `Data.Dynamic`:

```
import Data.Dynamic

ls = [toDyn (4 :: Int), toDyn (3.2 :: Double), toDyn True, toDyn "hello"]
```

With custom type:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

 data Any = forall a. {- here can be restrictions on `a` => -} Any a

 ls :: [Any]
 ls = [Any (4 :: Int), Any (3.2 :: Double), Any True, Any "home"]
```

If type set are closed, you can just use ADT:

```
 data Variant = I Int | D Double | B Bool | S String

 ls :: [Variant]
 ls = [I 4, D 3.2, B true, S "home"]
```

So, to select right solution need to know more about your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print everything in the list, you can use ExistentialQuantification to "hide" the fact that the types are anything beyond having a `Show` instance (or whatever instance you care about).

Here's a simple example (note the language extension - I know this works in GHC, not sure about other compilers):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Obj = forall a. (Show a) => Obj a

ls :: [Obj]
ls  = [Obj 4, Obj 3.2, Obj True, Obj "home"] 

printObj :: Obj -> IO ()
printObj (Obj x) = putStrLn (show x)

main = mapM printObj ls
```

Notice that your list isn't strictly the same as in your question, but `Obj` can take any type that has a `Show` instance.

Comment: Hey I was thinking exactly the same! I think that's could be the most correct one, for now, I will accept that

Answer (score 0):

I found something interesting that maybe is close enough, [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections)

```
data Showable a = forall a. Show a => MkShowable a

pack :: Show a => a -> Showable
pack = MkShowable

hlist :: [Showable]
hlist = [ pack 3
        , pack "house"
        , pack True
        , pack 'y'
        , pack (Just Nothing) ]

res = map (\(MkShowable v) -> show v) hlist
```